# Selecting more than one column in subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that selects the oldest record from table B, which contains multiple rows for each row in table A, and joins it to table A:

```
SELECT A.Surname, A.Fornames, A.DOB, 
(SELECT TOP 1 B.RegNumber
   FROM B
   WHERE B.ID=A.ID 
   ORDER BY B.Date ASC) AS RegNumber
FROM A
ORDER BY A.Surname;
```

This works great, however I also want to pull another column from table B. So I would have:

```
A.Surname, A.Fornames, A.DOB, B.RegNumber, B.RegDate
```

How can I do this, whilst still only getting the oldest record from table B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options, the first is to restructure your query using joins:

The principle is, you need to get the first date for each record in `B` grouped by `ID`:

```
SELECT  ID, MIN(Date) AS [FirstDate]
FROM    B
GROUP BY ID;
```

You can then JOIN this back to B, to filter the results, i.e.:

```
SELECT  B.*
FROM    B
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  ID, MIN(Date) AS [FirstDate]
            FROM    B
            GROUP BY ID
        ) AS B2
            ON B2.ID = B.ID
            AND B2.FirstDate = B.Date;;
```

You can then join this to Table A and select all the fields you need:

```
SELECT  A.Surname, A.Fornames, A.DOB, B.RegNumber, B.RegDate
FROM    (A
        INNER JOIN B
            ON B.ID = A.ID)
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  ID, MIN(Date) AS [FirstDate]
            FROM    B
            GROUP BY ID
        ) AS B2
            ON B2.ID = B.ID
            AND B2.FirstDate = B.Date
ORDER BY A.Surname;
```

An alterative way to use JOINs is:

```
SELECT  A.Surname, A.Fornames, A.DOB, B.RegNumber, B.RegDate
FROM    (A
        INNER JOIN B
            ON A.ID = B.ID)
        LEFT JOIN B AS B2
            ON B2.ID = B.ID
            AND B2.Date < B.Date
WHERE   B2.ID IS NULL
ORDER BY A.Surname;
```

This method works by joining to `B` twice, and the second time (`B2`) getting all the records that are earlier than the record in the first join (`B`), then by stating that `B2.ID` is null, you are effectively saying that you want all records in B, where a record with the same ID and an earlier date does not exist.

The second approach, is to just repeat your correlated subquery:

```
SELECT A.Surname, A.Fornames, A.DOB, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 B.RegNumber
        FROM B
        WHERE B.ID=A.ID 
        ORDER BY B.Date ASC) AS RegNumber
    (SELECT TOP 1 B.RegDate
        FROM B
        WHERE B.ID=A.ID 
        ORDER BY B.Date ASC) AS RegDate
FROM A
ORDER BY A.Surname;
```

If you are only accessing two columns from the table then there is little to separate the two methods, both require B to be read twice, however using JOINs tends to give the optimiser a better chance so I would veer towards this method. The other advantage is it gives you access to all the fields in `B`, so if you needed a third column, you wouldn't have to add a third correlated subquery.

Answer (score 3):

You can repeat the subquery:

```
SELECT A.Surname, A.Fornames, A.DOB, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 B.RegNumber
        FROM B
        WHERE B.ID=A.ID 
        ORDER BY B.Date ASC
       ) AS RegNumber,
       (SELECT min(b.Date)
        FROM B
        WHERE B.ID=A.ID 
       ) AS RegDate
FROM A
ORDER BY A.Surname;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this...

```
SELECT A.Surname, A.Fornames, A.DOB, B.RegNumber, B.RegDate
FROM A
JOIN (
    Select top 1 RegNumber, RegDate
    From B
    WHERE B.ID = A.ID
    Order By B.Date ASC
) B on A.ID = B.ID
ORDER BY A.Surname;
```

That is what I get for throwing together some code.  The above example returns a "id" could not be bound error.  Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I tried it with some sample code.

```
SELECT A.Surname, A.Fornames, A.DOB, MIN(B.RegNumber) As RegNumber, MIN(B.RegDate) as RegDate
FROM A
JOIN (
    Select ID, RegNumber, RegDate
    From B
) B on A.ID = B.ID
Group By A.Surname, A.Fornames, A.DOB
ORDER BY A.Surname;
```

Comment: The subquery has no access to fields in the outer query. I haven't used access recently enough to recall exactly the error that it will throw, but it will be along the lines of `A.ID` can't be bound, or may just prompt for a parameter.